# How to remove trailing and leading spaces based on delimiter '|' using tr utility?

Tags: unix, tr

Could anyone explain me how to remove trailing and leading spaces in file based on pipe ('|') delimiter using tr utility. Right now I'm using below command ,it removes spaces in the middle of the text as well.

```
 (tr -s '\n\r' < file.csv| tr '~' '\n' |sed "s/.$//" >  filetemp.csv && mv filetemp.csv file.csv)
```

Comment: You can't replace multiple parts of a line with `tr`.  Use `sed` instead.

Comment: Include sample input and expected output so that your requirement is very clear.  I just posted an answer that removes both leading and trailing spaces regardless of the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` instead:

```
sed -i -E 's/^[[:space:]]+//;s/[[:space:]]$//' file.csv
```

- `-i` does in-place substitution

Related:

- [Can tr work with regex? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86929/201820)